# For Loop of Synchronous Javascript Injections

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Currently, I am attempting to perform injections of a certain script for a variable amount of times in order (synchronously). Put simply, I want to be able to inject script xyz.js for Z amount of times.

I currently have the code to inject the script a hard-coded amount of times. This code looks like such:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.ib,{file: "inject.js"}, function(resp){
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.ib,{file: "inject.js"}, function(resp){
    });
});
```

With this method, I simply nest the injections into the callback functions of the previous injections. However, this method of synchronously calling multiple injections must be hard-coded in. As a result, I cannot perform this synchronous injection sequence a variable amount of times.

How can I change my code to allow me to inject the code synchronously a variable amount of times?

Note: These injections are injecting the same file because it is executing the content differently depending upon the webpage's conditions. Also note that it must be synchronous because the file's behavior depends upon the previous file injection. Finally, note that it cannot be simply combined into one large file because of how the program runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use recursion for this.

```
(function loop(n) {
  if(n > 1) chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.ib,{file: "inject.js"}, function(resp){
    loop(n - 1);
  });
})(10);
```